# as3 timer turn external device on and off

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I am trying to program a Phidgets device to repeatedly turn an external light on for .5 sec and off for .5 sec.

(these times correspond to Frames 1 and 11 of a 20 frame movie clip.

I've tried to insert the on- and off- commands into the movie clip, but they don't transfer to the main stage, so now I'm just trying to program the light to go on and off from the main program

The code below turns the light on and off at the SAME TIME- which means NOTHING HAPPENS.
Does anyone know how to delay the timer so that the off command comes 500 msec AFTER the on command ?
THanks

```
phid.addEventListener(PhidgetEvent.ATTACH,onAttach);
//connects Phidget to software 

function onAttach(evt:PhidgetEvent):void{
    trace(evt);
}
    var phidControl:Timer = new Timer (500);
    phidControl.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lightOn);
        function lightOn (evt:TimerEvent):void {

        phid.setOutputState(0, true);} //this turns the light on


    enter code here
    var phidOff:Timer = new Timer(500);
    phidControl.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lightOff);
     function lightOff(evt:TimerEvent):void {
         phid.setOutputState(0, false);//this turns light off
     }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response,
 I just spent the past 2 hours trying to modify my code according to your advice and Phidgets lingo
The code below turns the light on FOREVER. I need it to repeatedly cycle at 1 HZ (500 msec on , 500 msec OFF)
AM I doing something stupid?
Thanks in advance
val = true;
 
 var phidControl:Timer = new Timer(500,50000);
                phidControl.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lightOn);
                   function lightOn(evt:TimerEvent):void {
                     phid.setOutputState(0,val);
       }

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're creating two Timers which both run at a 500ms interval simultaneously.

It might be easier to put one function on a 500ms timer, which will call either function intermittently, something like

```
var lightIsOn = false;
function lightToggle(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    if(lightIsOn){
        lightOff();
    }else{
        lightOn();
    }
    lightIsOn = !lightIsOn;
}
```

---- UPDATE ----

I'm not very familiar with Phidgets, however that shouldn't make a difference in this case. Try this:

```
val = true;

var phidControl:Timer = new Timer(500); //If you don't set the repeat count it goes on forever

phidControl.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lightToggle);

    function lightToggle(evt:TimerEvent):void {
        val = !val;
        phid.setOutputState(0,val); 
    }
phidControl.start(); //Make sure you start the timer.
```

If you only want to switch it once every .5 seconds then you don't have to worry about reading the state of the light, just tell it when to change. So from what I can tell, you don't need the inputChange function.

Comment: tried to modify my code re your advice and Phidgets lingo
Code below turns the light on FOREVER. Need repeated cycling at 1 HZ (500 msec on , 500 msec OFF)            function inputChange(evt:PhidgetEvent):void {
          if (phid.getOutputState(0))
     {if (val = true) {
                    val = false;
    }}}.


Thanks in advance
val = true;
 var phidControl:Timer = new Timer(500,50000);
                phidControl.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lightOn);
                   function lightOn(evt:TimerEvent):void {
                     phid.setOutputState(0,val);
       }